# Can sphinx count all words in its index using morphology?

Tags: indexing, sphinx

I want to rate most frequently words in sphinx index. The only one method I found it's `/usr/bin/indexer -c /etc/sphinxsearch/sphinx.conf indexname --buildfreqs --buildstops /home/user/test.txt 1000`. But this method doesn't consider morphology. One word in different forms counting as several words. Maybe there's another method for count all indexed words?

Comment: Have you tried `indextool --dumpdict` ? Provided a dict=keywords index think it will help.

Comment: I tried to to dumpdict but it anyway doesn't use morphology forms.

Comment: Are you sure? I think it HAS to. because only the morphed version is stored in index. It needs to be the morthed version so that keywords actully match. dumpdict is dumping the actual dictionary from the index! - just checked on one of my indexes, and it contains `bridg,2738,6794,11805033` - but which is the 'normalized' version. that word on its own doesnt exist

Comment: Oh, really. I didn't understand clearly what is in output. Now I see. Really works. Thanks. Write the answer, I will choose the best one yours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in comments, can use `indextool --dumpdict` - which should give the word counts from the index. Because its from the index, its already been 'normalized' as per charset_table, wordforms, and even morphology.

(but only works on a `dict=keywords` index)